# Getting regional minima coordinates in ITK

Tags: image-processing, itk

I'm new to ITK and would like to get the locations of the regional minima (intensity) of a blurred 2D image. After applying `itk::RegionalMinimaImageFilter`, I'd like to store these points in a vector. My code for that specific part looks as follows:

```
// find regional minima
typedef itk::RegionalMinimaImageFilter <FloatImageType, ImageType > RegionalMinimaImageFilterType;
RegionalMinimaImageFilterType::Pointer regionalMinimaImageFilter = RegionalMinimaImageFilterType::New ();
regionalMinimaImageFilter->SetInput(gaussianFilter->GetOutput());
regionalMinimaImageFilter->Update();
```

After this, I guess I need to call `regionalMinimaImageFilter->GetIndexedOutputs();`, but I'm not so sure. How can I get the positions of the regional minima in an easy way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something you can do is simply go through the output with an index iterator, storing the coordinates of all pixels having a value equal to foreground value you set in RegionalMinimaImageFilter using the `SetForegroundValue` method> It could be done more or less like this (haven't tested the code):

```
//Declare an iterator of a given type to iterate in all the image
//See how to declare the iterator type in the example given
IteratorType outputIt( outputImage, filter->GetOutput()->GetRequestedRegion());

//Go to the begin of the image
outputIt.GoToBegin();

//Iterate over the image
while( !outputIt.IsAtEnd() )
{
    if ( outputIt.Get() == filter->GetForegroundValue () ) {
        ImageType::IndexType idx = outputIt.GetIndex();
        //Print the coordinates of the pixel 
        //This are array coordinates, to get 'world' coordinates
        //multiply by spacing and add origin
        std::cout << "Coordinates : " << idx[0] << "," << idx[1] << std::endl;
    }
    ++outputIt; //Go to the next pixel
}
```

This is the standard way to go through an ITK image, regardless of the dimensions. It will first go through the first dimension and then to the second and so on.

The complete example for the use of index iterators can be found here: http://www.itk.org/Doxygen45/html/Iterators_2ImageRegionIteratorWithIndex_8cxx-example.html

Also you may read about iterators in the section 6.3 of the ITK manual (http://www.itk.org/ItkSoftwareGuide.pdf).

Comment: Yes, this is one way of doing it. I made some minor edits to the answer. cheers!

Comment: Thanks, you improve it. You said that "this is one way of doing it". Please add another answer with the other solution! I'm curious :) Cheers!

Comment: Oh, it was a general comment.. I still think one could probably do it using `GetIndexedOutputs`, but i'm not sure.